# Using C++ code in a C program and Vice-Versa

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, dynamic-linking

I'm currently writing an interface between a very low level C program to a higher level  C++ program. The way they relate is through a linked list: The C program has a linked list, and the interface takes the information stored in each node in the linked list and converts that to a C++ vector. The process itself it's not a program. The problem is how to call that C++ function from the C program. Let me give you some light on that:

```
int importData(List *head, char * source, char * dest);
```

is declared in the C++ file, called `import_helper.cpp`. I defined the declaration, and shown above, and then the implementation, so the compile wouldn't complain. In `import.c`, the C program, I'm trying to invoke that function: Remember, List is a struct defined in `import.c`
Now, in `import.c` I have:

```
#if defined(_cplusplus)
extern 'C' {
#endif
typedef struct list{
   struct list *next
   .. other additional data goes here ...
}List;

int importData(List *head, char *source, char *dest);
#if defined(_cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

And in `import_helper.cpp` header I do an `#include "import.c"`. `import.c` does not have a .h file (someone wrote that code, I personally consider that a mistake itself).

When I compile, I get:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'class'
error: conflicts with the new declaration with 'C' linking
error: previous declaration of 'void getPassword(char *)' with 'C++' linkage
```

That's just a sample. However, I believe `import.c` is compiled with `gcc` and my `Build` file compiles `import_help.cpp` with `g++`. Could that be the reason? I had other files with the similar approach, so I'm not so sure on that. Any Thought?
Thanks

Comment: This seems overly complicated. You can easily call C code from C++. Why not just wrap the C functions in a class?

Comment: Because the C program is meant for one task, and the C++ code is meant for another task, but they need to 'talk'

Comment: The point is to transform a C linked list in a C++ vector. This is easily done. The program is how to invoke that C++ function from a C program, passing that linked list to the C++ program.

Comment: So, is interprocess communication an option? Otherwise, write a `extern C` function that calls the `C++` function.

Comment: Just use g++ for everything, I'd say (unless you're using strange C99 stuff it doesn't understand?). Or manage your headerfiles more carefully

Comment: @Rook. That's probably the solution, but it may be too complicated, because depends on other stuff. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a `import_helper.h` file, then in `import_helper.cpp` I had it included (`#include "import_helper.h"`) in both `import_helper.cpp` and `import.c`.
In `import_helper.h` I have:

```
extern "C"{
   typedef struct list{
      ... /*some code goes here */
      struct list* next;
   }List;
   int importData(List *, char*, char*);
}
```

So both the `.c` and the `.cpp` share the same data.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the common code between the two projects by writing a DLL that uses C++ on the back-end. So long as the declarations are made for C you should be able to call the defined methods from either a C or C++ program.

Comment: There is a two way extern on that:
The `List` `struct` is used in the `C++` function, and the `importData(List*, char*, char*)` function is used in the `C` program.

Comment: Can you export both from the DLL header file?

Comment: Are you combining both programs into a single executable, or are you using an IPC method such as a Shared Memory Object?

You will need to keep the definition of importData in C, so as far as I know you can't use STL vector or "new" calls in the body of that function. Can you change that function to copy List* into a global instance of List accessible to import_helper? Then "signal" import_helper to read that instance and map to a C++ vector...

Answer (score 0):

When you define importData in the .cpp file, you need to put it in an extern "C" (note the double quotes) block as well:

```
extern "C"{
    int importData(List *head, char *source, char *dest){
        blah blah blah
        ...
    }
}
```

And from the error `void getPassword(char *)` needs it, too.

Answer (score 0):

C++ can throw exceptions.

Make sure your "C" interface into the C++ code catches everything, and returns a error status, and maybe some sort of cstring like message, so you don't get any unexpected program terminations.

Comment: I have a `vserror(const char* message, const int errcode)` that catches the error in `C` which I'm using in the `C++` function.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch to catch all exceptions?